# React-Native IOS: Background-Timer doesnt run in the Background

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, task, background-task

iam trying to start a Background-Timer.
I want to run code, that will be performing for iOS on background too.

I use the
[react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) libary.

But when i minimize the App the code doesnt run.
I run the App in the simulator as well as on my IOS-Device (Debug and Release).
But the code doesnt run when the App is minimized.

My Code:

```
var myTimer;

componentDidMount(): void {
    const time = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                const location = JSON.stringify(position);
                console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                this.setState({
                    location,
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                });
            });
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to  library [documentation](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) BackgroundTimer.setInterval is used only for android . if you need Crossplatform To use the same code both on Android and iOS use runBackgroundTimer() and stopBackgroundTimer()

```
BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => { 
//code that will be called every 3 seconds 
}, 
3000);
//rest of code will be performing for iOS on background too

BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer(); //after this call all code on background stop run.
```

Answer (score 0):

**This work for me** In case official documentation not work

```
const PromiseValue = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => {
      resolve();
        reject()
    }, 3000);
  });
  PromiseValue.finally(() =>
    BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer(),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check on checkbox "Background processing" in the Background modes section. Take a look on the screenshot
[image]